# Calculating ratios between two shapefiles with Python

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, overlapping-features, calculate-values

So I have two shapefiles, one is a grid and one is a map of the world's land. I am trying to find the ratio of land in each cell of the 'grid' shapefile to show the land/water ratio but I'm stuck.

[Here are the shapefiles](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1zR37cB07NWovuHeATInWjS0hRRVcZgdI)

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import point, Polygon, mapping, shape

grid = gpd.read_file('grid.shp')
World_Land = gpd.read_file("World_Land.shp")

for index1, row1 in World_Land.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in grid.iterrows():
        if row1['geometry'].intersection(row2['geometry']):
            grid.loc[index2,'ratio'] = (row1['geometry'].area / row2['geometry'].area)

grid.plot(column = 'ratio')
```

This gives me something but I want to make sure I am making a choropleth map correctly and calculating the ratios correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
import geopandas as gpd
land = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Downloads/ratio/Ratio Help/World_Land.shp")
grid = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Downloads/ratio/Ratio Help/grid.shp")

# grid.columns
# Index(['ID', 'Land', 'geometry', 'original_area'], dtype='object')

grid["original_area"] = grid.geometry.area
inter = gpd.overlay(df1=land, df2=grid, how="intersection")
inter["interarea"] = inter.geometry.area

#Each grid cell can intersect multiple land areas. Calculate sum per grid cell..
inter = inter.groupby(by=["ID","original_area"], as_index=False)["interarea"].sum() 

#Calculate the ratio of land
inter["landratio"] = inter.apply(lambda x: x["interarea"]/x["original_area"], axis=1)

grid = gpd.pd.merge(left=grid, right=inter[["ID","landratio"]], on="ID")

ax = grid.plot(column="landratio", figsize=(10,5), legend=True, cmap="winter")
land.boundary.plot(ax=ax, edgecolor="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution! However, for calculating area I will use EPSG:3857 like this `grid = grid.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})`, and then `grid["original_area"] = grid.geometry.area / 10**6`, see https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.area.html#geopandas-geoseries-area